# disable make a copy of documents in m-files

Tags: windows

I want to disable make a copy option when user do right click on documents in `m-files`, until no body cant copy documents to other class to use, 
is there anybody to help me to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with [M-Files User Interface Extensibility Framework](https://developer.m-files.com/Frameworks/User-Interface-Extensibility-Framework/).

The needed function is [`shellFrame.Commands.SetCommandState(9, CommandLocation_All, 3)`](https://www.m-files.com/UI_Extensibility_Framework/MFClientScript~ICommands~SetCommandState.html).

- 1st parameter is command ID ([list of built-in command IDs](https://www.m-files.com/UI_Extensibility_Framework/MFClientScript~BuiltinCommand.html), `9` is `BuiltinCommand_MakeCopy`)
- 2nd parameter defines the parts of the UI where you want to set the new command state
- 3rd parameter defines the new state (`3` is `CommandState_Hidden`)

You will need to set up the UI extension with some configuration files but there is a sample that comes close to your use-case: [Alter Context Menu Depending on SelectedObject](https://github.com/M-Files/MFilesSamplesAndLibraries/tree/master/Samples/UIX%20Applications/AlterContextMenuDependingOnSelectedObject/#readme). The code to hide the context menu option in `main.js` would be:

```
"use strict";

function OnNewShellUI(shellUI) {
    shellUI.Events.Register(
        Event_NewNormalShellFrame,
        handleNewNormalShellFrame);
}

function handleNewNormalShellFrame(shellFrame) {
    shellFrame.Events.Register(
        Event_Started,
        getShellFrameStartedHandler(shellFrame));
}

function getShellFrameStartedHandler(shellFrame) {
    return function () {
        shellFrame.Commands.SetCommandState(9, CommandLocation_All, 3);
    };
}
```